# LESS Repeat selector declaration inside a mixin

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'm trying to declare background image icons for some table rows:

```
.i(@file:'file.png', @type) {
    &.@{type} {
      td:first-child {
        background-image: url('../img/@{file}');
      }
    }
  }
```

I'd like to be able to pass in multiple image types at once:

```
.i('code.png', 'asp, php, rb, py')
```

and have it effectively do this:

```
.i(@file:'file.png', @type) {
  &.@{type1},
  &.@{type2},
  &.@{type3},
  &.@{type4}, {
    td:first-child {
      background-image: url('../img/@{file}');
    }
  }
}
```

I know the CSS output will be different, the last code example is for illustration purposes.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, short of just declaring a bunch of empty selectors as placeholders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updated for LESS 1.5

This code produces the same effect more efficiently in the later versions of LESS, using the newer `extract()` and `length()` functions available in LESS 1.5+. Output will be the same as the original example.

```css
.i(@file:'file.png', @types) {

  //find length to make the stop point
  @stopIndex: length(@types);

  //set up our LESS loop (recursive)
  .loopTypes (@index) when (@index =< @stopIndex) {
    @class: extract(@types,@index);
    //print the CSS
    &.@{class} {
        td:first-child {
          background-image: url('../img/@{file}');
        }
      }

        // next iteration
        .loopTypes(@index + 1);
    }

    // "call" the loopingClass the first time getting first item
    .loopTypes (1);
}

.myClass {
  .i('code.png'; asp, php, rb, py;);
}
```

### With Loops and Inline-Javascript in LESS 1.3.3

This took a few hours to come up with (no, I didn't have a bunch of free time to work on it, I'm just hopelessly addicted...). One of the parts that took the longest was figuring out why my `@stopIndex` was not being seen as a number by LESS when I was returning the `.length` of the array, and throwing a type error. I finally discovered I need to explicitly tell it to see it as a number using the `unit()` function of LESS.

The solution utilizes general concepts from these sources:

1. The [LESS looping](http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/)
2. The [Javascript functions in LESS](http://movableapp.com/2012/08/execute-complex-javascript-in-lesscss/)

**LESS**

```
.i(@file:'file.png', @type) {
  //find length to make the stop point
  @stopIndex: unit(`(function(){ return @{type}.split(",").length})()`);
  //need to get the first item in @type
  @firstClass: ~`(function(){ 
      var clsArray = @{type}.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(",");   
      return clsArray[0]; 
    })()`;

  //set up our LESS loop (recursive)
  .loopTypes (@index, @captureClass) when (@index < @stopIndex) {
    @nextClass: ~`(function(){ 
      var clsArray = @{type}.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(",");
      //don't let it try to access past array length
      if(@{index} < (@{stopIndex} - 1)) {
       return clsArray[@{index} + 1]; 
      } 
      else { return '' }
    })()`;

    //print the CSS
    &.@{captureClass} {
        td:first-child {
          background-image: url('../img/@{file}');
        }
      }

        // next iteration
        .loopTypes(@index + 1, @nextClass);
    }

    // define guard expressoin to end the loop when past length
    .loopTypes (@stopIndex, @captureClass) {}

    // "call" the loopingClass the first time getting first item
  .loopTypes (0, @firstClass);
}

.myClass {
  .i('code.png', 'asp, php, rb, py');
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.myClass.asp td:first-child {
  background-image: url('../img/code.png');
}
.myClass.php td:first-child {
  background-image: url('../img/code.png');
}
.myClass.rb td:first-child {
  background-image: url('../img/code.png');
}
.myClass.py td:first-child {
  background-image: url('../img/code.png');
}
```

Comment: I sure did get in a mess trying to do this myself :)